# How to sort date and string in same column in jquery plugin having file jquery.dataTables.js?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, sorting

I have a table containing "Date(in format M/d like 'Aug-23')"  and string(like 'process' and 'completed') in same column. But the issue is that it is sorted alphabetically not sort according to Date. 
And structure of my file is:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="../../table-sorting/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="../../table-sorting/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>      
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" class="init">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#sorting').dataTable( {
            "dom": '<"top"iflp<"clear">>rt<"bottom"iflp<"clear">>'
        } );
    } );
</script>
```

> CPA      Shipping
>
> 123    Aug-28
>
> 327  July-30
>
> 789  Process

if i sort shipping column then it give result like

> Process
>
> Aug-28
>
> July-30

But i want result like:

> Process
>
> July-30
>
> Aug-28

means firstly string sorting and after that date sorting

And these shipping values are coming from Mysql database

How I solve this issue??
Any Suggestion??

Comment: You could use the jQuery method `split(" ")` to separate the two values according to where the space is and then sort them individually.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write your dates in `YYYYmmdd` format so that alphabetical order matches chronological order.
But you want your dates to be displayed in a better-looking format (legit).

The solution is to have 2 columns: one with the good-looking date, one with the `YYYYmmdd` date. This one will be hidden, but will be used by `dataTable` sorting function.

```
<table id="sorting">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>CPA</th>
            <th>Shipping</th>
            <th>Shipping (sorting format)</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>Aug 28</td>
            <td>20150828</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>327</td>
            <td>July 30</td>
            <td>20150730</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>789</td>
            <td>Process</td>
            <td>0</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Then, the Javascript :

```
$('#sorting').dataTable( {
    "aoColumns": [
        {"bSortable": true}, // First column: normal
        {"iDataSort": 2}, // Second column's sorting depends on third column (dataTable starts counting from 0, that's why third column is number 2)
        {"bVisible": false}, // Third column: hide it
    ]
});
```

You'll find more tips and examples in [DataTables' documentation](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/columns).

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer but the issue is that i have 9 columns heading  (like Shipping, Install, Pre-Trim) which comes in array from mysql database and all tables connected to each other as foreign key.
 So its too complicated to solve the problem according to provided solution by you.

Comment: Just fill `aoColumns` in Javascript code for your 9 columns.